# Solving parametric equation for absolut value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
|x^2-1|+|x-a|=0.
$$
Firstly thats not a $l$ but a $1$. The problem says solve: simple as that. I don´t know how to do it. Never tackled such kind of problems

Comment: Absolut Value $\equiv$ how much a bottle of vodka is worth :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy: $x^2-1=0$ and $x=a$, since the sum of two non-negative quantities can be zero if and only if they are *both* zero.

Hence $a^2=1$, or $a \in \{-1,1\}$.

Comment: won´t the terms also account for negative terms?and be both negative and positive ? Why only sum of two positive quantities?

Comment: What is "it"? Absolute values are non-negative, and vanish only where their argument vanishes.

Comment: x^2-1=0 and -x^2+1=0 ?

Comment: Please read: $|x^2-1|$ is not the same as $x^2-1$. $|x^2-1| \geq 0$ for any $x$, and it equals zero only at $x^2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the $|x|$ definition one can solve this,$$|x|=\begin{cases}
x& \text{ if } x>0\\
-x&\text{ if }  x<0\\
0&\text{ if } x=0
\end{cases}$$

two non-negative reals gives zero means each must be zero.
so, $$|x^2-1|=0\implies x^2-1=0\implies x=\pm1\tag{1}$$
$$|x-a|=0\implies x-a=0\implies x=a\tag{2}$$
Solving the simultaneous equation $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $x=a=\pm 1$

Answer (score 0):

it must be $|x^2-1|=0$ and $|x-a|=0$ therefore we get
$a=-1,x=-1$ or $a=1,x=1$